# violation of primary key ???? even when there is a chk not to insert the record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
INSERT INTO table 2
SELECT values FROM table 1  LEFT JOIN table 2
ON 1.col1 = 2.col1 and
   1.col2 = 2.col2 and
   1.col3 = 2.col3 
WHERE 
( 
   2.col1   IS NULL AND
   2.col2   IS NULL AND
   2.col3   IS NULL
)
```

col1,col2,col3 primary keys for table 2

Also did a inner join  on condition primary key <>
added a if not exists ( select 1 from table 2 join table 1 on primary keys = )
always get violation of primary key error cannot insert

please help

Comment: Have you just ran the SELECT by itself to check the output? You might see where the dupe is coming from then.

Comment: YES IN FACT I REMOVE DUPLICATES FROM TABLE 1 BEFORE INSERT

Comment: there is one more proc running b4 my proc that inserts or updates into the same table that is y i chk if the record is already there

Comment: even added SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
           BEGIN TRANSACTION

Comment: do not want to use a while loop and do it one row at a time, i remove any duplicates in table 1. in table 1 i have a identity column and delete from table 1 where identity not in ( select max(identity) from table 1 group by col1,col2,col3) then even did select distinct before insert

Comment: works fine when i fetch records into variables and then check on table 2 b4 insert or update.....

Comment: The use of BLOCK CAPITALS and txt spk has put me right off participating in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to figure out why you're getting the problem you're seeing, I suggest you re-write your SQL to use the MERGE command. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

It allows you to specify what to do if there is a duplicate record or not.

As a note, if you wish to ensure a stored procedure runs exclusively (you hinted at this), you need the following:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE            -- most restrictive

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN

            DECLARE @LockResult int

            SET @LockName = 'MyLockName'

            EXEC    @LockResult = sp_getapplock @Resource = @LockName, @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockTimeout = 0

            if @LockResult <> 0 begin
                SET @Failed = 1
            end else begin
                -- WORK HERE
            end

            -- FINALIZE TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            -- CATCH CODE
        END CATCH

        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED  -- set back to default
```